# A PMF of demand for humanitarian meals based on a Time Series

Tags: time-series, density-function

Given previous quarterly data on the demand for humanitarian meals, how should I create a Probability Mass Function (PMF) of demand per year?  I do not seek an actual function; a table of probabilities of annual demand would be perfect.  For example:

```
Annual
Demand      Probability    
  500,000   .25
1,000,000   .32
...
```

I've considered using ARIMA or Holt-Winters exponential smoothing, but I only know how to use these to forecast future values.  I don't know how to create a PMF/PDF using these methods.

I have data from 29 previous quarters.  Here is the `R` code to create the dataframe.

```
meals <-
structure(list(Decimal.year = c(2008.25, 2008.5, 2008.75, 2009, 
2009.25, 2009.5, 2009.75, 2010, 2010.25, 2010.5, 2010.75, 2011, 
2011.25, 2011.5, 2011.75, 2012, 2012.25, 2012.5, 2012.75, 2013, 
2013.25, 2013.5, 2013.75, 2014, 2014.25, 2014.5, 2014.75, 2015, 
2015.25), Shipped = c(3015000, 738000, 15823000, 325000, 
1629000, 92000, 116000, 21000, 2033000, 2275000, 539000, 0, 302000, 
3262000, 3029000, 586000, 109000, 0, 5811000, 4099000, 0, 95000, 
0, 44000, 1044000, 0, 214000, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-29L), .Names = c("Decimal.year", "Shipped"))
```

Plotting the data does seem to show a seasonal component, but no trend.  This makes sense, given that demand is based on disaster events, including seasonal storms.

```
plot(meals, typ="l", col="brown", lwd=3, main="Humanitarian Meals Demand")
```

[image: Humanitarian Meals Demand]